# Drawing a DFA for L= { a^n b^n , n>0}

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

Could someone explain how to do this?
This is homework and I'm fairly new when it comes to programming.

Comment: You shouldn't ask a question in SO that is a homework because the homework is for thinking about your course and it helps you to improve your skills.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a regular language and therefore there is no DFA which accepts it. You can prove this using the pumping lemma or the Myhill-Nerode theorem.